# Files when unzipped are much larger (60x) than .gz

Tags: compression, gzip, vcf-variant-call-format

I have downloaded 1000 genome .vcf files from the 1000genomes website using:

```
wget ftp://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/release/20130502//*.gz
```

I tried to use gzip to unzip these files but they unzipped to a much larger size than the originals. For instance, the first file (for chromosome 1) was 1.1gb zipped, but expanded to 65.78gb.

Thinking it may be an issue with gzip, I tried two other methods. One was to run the annotation tool snpEff directly on the .gz file and the other was to use zcat to unzip the file. However in both instances the file sizes were similarly huge.

I am assuming this cannot be right, but do not know why this is the case. Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Comment: Mmmmm...I think that it is obvious to must of us that a `compressed` file has a smaller size than the original `uncompressed` file...I don't see this as an anomaly, actually, it's pretty normal, at least in this realm....

Comment: Where did you get the original file sizes? The FTP site only seems to offer the compressed versions. Check start and end of files; does it look correct?

Comment: I am aware that a compressed file will be smaller, but is that much of a reduction in size possible? The start and end of the files look as they should do.

Comment: Yes, with text like files it is possible to get that compression ratio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked out the chromosome 1 file and it's fine. I presume all the rest are as well. Yes, data that highly redundant can compress that much. It's only compressed 60:1, where gzip is capable of compressing as much as 1032:1.

The stream is broken up into individually gzipped pieces of 64K of uncompressed data each for the purpose of indexing. (The associated "tbi" files contain the locations of each piece in the big gzip file.) Had they just compressed it as a single stream, or with index points a good bit farther apart, it would have compressed about 68:1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mark. Turns out it is due to the reason for the massive difference is that most of the data consist of the allele representations: 0|0 or 1|0 with no other information in each column. Hence most of the file consists of long rows of 0|0s.